Has every homogeneous Banach space on the torus an operator S_n (Katznelson on Harmonic Analysis)?
In his book about Harmonic Analysis Katznelson defines homogeneous Banach spaces on the 1-dim. torus: in short, such a space is a linear subspace $B$ of $L^1(\mathbb T)$ with a norm denoted $||f||_B$ (for $f \in B$) $\ge ||f||_1$ for which B is complete, stable by translation ($f \mapsto f_h$ where $f_h(t) = f(t-h)$) which doesn't alter this B-norm and continuity of the translation as a mapping $h \mapsto f_h$ from $\mathbb T$ into $B$.
Later he considers an operator $f \mapsto S_n(f)$ where as usual, for a function $f$ with Fourier series $\sum_{k \in \mathbb Z} a_k e^{ikt}$, $S_n(f)$ is $t \mapsto \sum_{k=-n}^n a_k e^{ikt}$. He then states that this operator "is well defined in every homogeneous Banach space $B$"; this seems to mean that $(f \in B) \implies (S_n(f) \in B)$ given the ordinary use of the word operator. This is indeed true for the examples of homogeneous Banach spaces he gives, but I see no reason why it should follow from the definition of such spaces, so I wonder whether it is even true in this generality. Could it be that the values of the operator are not supposed to be in $B$, although that would make the statement too trivial to be worth mentioning, or is there a trick to show he is right with my interpretation?
Addendum: the next thing in the book is the introduction and use of a symbol for the norm of said operator; this makes it clear that the operator is really considered as from $B$ to $B$ (still implicitely but only this interpretation remains possible) ... (end of Addendum)
BTW does someone know where the definition of homogeneous B. sp. comes from? (I consider the idea really useful, but estimate that the name given is not well chosen, and guess Katznelson coined it, finding it nowhere else.) In fact one can find elsewhere that: An infinite dimensional Banach space is said to be homogeneous provided it is isomorphic to each of its infinite dimensional subspaces; this doesn't seem to be equivalent for subspaces of the mentioned $L^1$ (and if it were, that would be far from obvious).

Katznelson mentions this very briefly: if $f\in B$ and $k\in L^1(\mathbb T)$, then the convolution $kf$ can be written as the integral of a $B$-valued function, and therefore is an element of $B$. In particular, $S_n(f)=D_nf\in B$ whenever $f\in B$. I have no idea where Katznelson's notion of homogeneous Banach space comes from though.

Yes I had found that out too in the mean time because I looked again at chapt.1 where this is used already. I'm not sure though whether this works also for $k$ only integrable, what is needed is $k \in C(\mathbb T)$ and in that case it's OK. Very important in this context is that the $B$-norm is $\ge$ the $L^1$-norm making the inclusion injection $B \rightarrow L^1(\mathbb T)$ linear continuous. I intended to give my question an answer myself, having made this discovery; I'll do it when I have time

In fact, Katznelson's assertion is correct!
I will use without proof the following lemma from Katznelson's book in section 2.4. of chapt.1 (where you can read the not so short original proof using Riemann sums in the case $f$ continuous, for which I prefer an alternative of my own):
Lemma: If $f \in L^1(\mathbb T)$ and $k:\mathbb T \rightarrow \mathbb C$ is continuous, then $(2 \pi)^{-1} \int_{\mathbb T}k(t)f_t dt = k*f$.
Here the sign $*$ stands for convolution (roughly $g*h(t)=\int_{\mathbb T}g(v)h(t-v)dv/2\pi$). And one must understand that the integral in the lemma has an integrand which is a vector-valued function (product of the scalar function $k$ and the vector function $t \mapsto f_t$ which are both continuous, the second due to the definition of a hom. B. space) so that the integrand itself is continuous - this being valid independently of whether one considers $B$ or $L^1(\mathbb T)$ as target space (in case $f \in B$).
Next the condition in the definition of a homogeneous Banach space saying that $||f||_B \ge ||f||_1$ implies that the inclusion map $j: B \rightarrow L^1(\mathbb T)$ (which is linear) is continuous. A nearly trivial result on vector-valued integration says that you can swap integration and a linear continuous map. Apply this to $j$ and you get that the integral of the lemma can be taken in $B$ as well as in $L^1(\mathbb T)$ and has the same value in both variants. On other words the integral of the lemma belongs to $B$ while in the lemma (in which $B$ is not mentioned) it is of course supposed to be taken in $L^1$.
Now we take $k = D_n$ where the $D_n (n \in \mathbb N)$ stand collectively for the so-called Dirichlet kernel (which is not "good"); for details about this, look in Katznelson's book (chapt.1, section 2.9.) or in Wikipedia (article Dirichlet kernel). The lemma - together with last paragraph - tells us that $S_n(f) = D_n * f \in B$ when $f \in B$. This confirms what Katznelson writes in his book.
